# Is it possible to stop workflow from child publication?

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow

I am sending a component to World Server for translation from the parent publication through workflow. Once the translation is completed it automatically starts the same workflow for the that component but from all the child publication.

The only way I have found is Bundle. But apart from that is there any way to handle this situation ?

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflow is automatically started because you have component process associated with component's schema.

To prevent the workflow to be started you need to localize schema in child publication and remove component process.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to localise the schema in every child publication (as in Stanislav's answer) or you still need a component process for regular edits you could also add an automatic decision step to the workflow which by-passes the other steps if the workflow has been started by the Translation Manager user.

Comment: Thanks Devid. I think adding an automatic decision activity will be the better idea to resolve my problem.

Comment: @Devid , But I cant add a automatic decision activity as a first activity.

Comment: This should be possible with 2013SP1. Have you updated your Visio add-in, as you need the 2013SP1 version?